# Doctrine: set foreign relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This is regarding a problem with Doctrine when I try to insert a record into a associative entity. Below is a simplified description of the problem.

I have two tables, let's call them `One` and `Two`. Table `One` has a foreign key to table `Two`, called `twoId` with a column `two_id`. Field `two_id` happens to be part of the primary key.

```
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="string", length=40)
 */
private $twoId;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="[...]", inversedBy="[...]", fetch="EAGER")
 * @JoinColumn(name="two_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $two;
```

I am trying to insert a new record into table A. This works:

```
$two = [.. read from DB ..];
$one = new One();

$one->setTwo($two);
$one->setTwoId($two->getId());

$em->persist($one);
$em->flush();
```

I don't like to call both `setTwo` and `setTwoId`. Furthermore, I don't like reading the `$two` record before referencing it.

If I skip `setTwoId` call, I get the error: Entity of type [..] is missing an assigned ID for field 'twoId'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called.

If I skip `setTwo` call, I get the error: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'two_id' cannot be null

My problems are:

1. **How can I avoid calling both `setTwo()` and `setTwoId()`?**
2. What if I want to reference a entity from `Two` **without reading it**? Should I use `$em->getReference()`? (PhpStorm doesn't even recognize it)

Comment: we need to see the code for the models. I am wondering why you have a `setTwoId()` function at all on the `One` entity. Regarding your second question: using the reference on the entityManager requires knowing the id. It will get the object via proxy class and will hydrate it as soon as you try to access further attributes on that class, so yes you can use it to reference it.

Comment: You are right @lordrhodos, having a `setTwoId` function was a bad idea. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone makes the same mistake:

As pointed out by @lordrhodos, declaring the field `$twoId` was wrong because Doctrine will create it automatically without having a definition.

Definition:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="[...]", inversedBy="[...]", fetch="EAGER")
 * @JoinColumn(name="two_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $two;
```

Usage:

```
$two = [.. read from DB ..];
$one = new One();

$one->setTwo($two);

$em->persist($one);
$em->flush();
```